# Can change monitor resolution of a SyncMaster SA850 and Intel HD graphics

Tags: debian, resolution

I have installed Debian 7.2 from liveUSB and connected the monitor Samsung SyncMaster SA850 with DVI cable into integrated Intel HD graphics. However I have very low resolution and can't change it. In addition, the system doesn't want to shut down (drivers update didn't help). With VGA cable everything works fine.

Configuration: I have ASUS H87-Pro motherboard and Intel Core i7-4770K.
Linux kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the resolution manually using `xrandr`:

1. List the screens available on your system:

   ```
   xrandr
   ```

   > Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
   >     LVDS1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   >     *[list of supported resolutions]*
   >     VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   >     HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   >     DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
2. `xrandr` expects a "ModeLine", which you can compute from a given resolution using `cvt`. I will be using your monitor's maximum resolution as an example (make sure your graphics card supports it):

   ```
   cvt 2560 1440
   ```

   > # 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
   >   Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
3. Use the ModeLine from above to create a new mode:

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
   ```
4. Add the newly created mode to the graphic output you want to use (see the `xrandr` output from step 1), then switch to it:

   ```
   xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "2560x1440_60.00"
   xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode "2560x1440_60.00"
   ```

If this fails, you might need to reboot your system to discard the change.
If it succeeds, add the `--newmode`, `--addmode` and `--output` commands to the `.profile` in your home directory, so they will be applied automatically when you log in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have an error with `xrandr` `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue what might be causing this. However, this [forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594308) suggests that it might be a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a driver problem. Solution from http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=111521.

Tell Synaptic Package Manager to use `contrib` and `non-free` packages (alternatively edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file).

Reload package information.

Search for `firmware-linux-nonfree` and install the package.

If the issue still persists after installing the package, try again with `xrandr` as instructed by @n.st.